# How to find Spring Boot auto-configuration classes that are activated by adding a specific starter project to pom?

Tags: spring-boot

How Spring Boot auto-configuration classes are activated based on the maven starter projects that are included in project `pom.xml` as dependencies?

for example, by adding `spring-boot-starter-security` to `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

class `SecurityAutoConfiguration` is activated. how does this happen? How `SecurityAutoConfiguration` is related to `spring-boot-starter-security`?

the starter project themselves are completely empty, there is no java code in these starter projects, and just a couple of dependencies is defined in `pom.xml`. I want to know exactly what happens when I add a starter project to my Spring Boot project and exactly what configurations are applied.

Comment: You don't as it isn't related to the starters, but rather the dependencies the starters pull in. So in this case the `spring-security` dependencies. The same would happen if you manually added the `spring-security` dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoconfiguration is one, or maybe the main one, feature of SpringBoot
Basically, depending on certain conditions, some configurations or/and beans are made available.
In your case here is what happens :

- *[spring-boot-starter-security](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.7.1)*, as other starters, is just here to make some others dependencies available for your project, particulary *[spring-security-config](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/5.7.2)* which itself, has a dependency on *spring-security-core*
- If your looking at the code source of [SecurityAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SecurityAutoConfiguration.java#L41) you can see that is configuration class depends on the availabality of the class DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher, which is true as now  you have a (transitive) dependency on *spring-security-core*.
- This SecurityAutoConfiguration class is listed as a Autoconfiguration class inside the config file [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports) (spring.factories for some previous Spring Boot version) of the spring-boot-autoconfigure project, which make it active for your application.

Here you can find the documentation :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.understanding-auto-configured-beans

Comment: this does not answer my question. given a starter project, how to find affected auto-conf classes?

Comment: Same answer but shorter : adding a starter project -> brings new dependencies -> bring new classes available in the classpath -> activate conditional Autoconfiguration classes

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration

Basically, either property for the starter can be disabled or exclude specific auto configuration from @springboot(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
)